# What exactly is a potential energy surface?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I first learned about potential energy surface (PES) when I was studying Born-Oppenheimer approximation. In the approximation, **the PES is essentially electronic PES** which is defined as follows:

Given the Hamiltonian of a molecule
$$\hat H = \hat T_{\text{nucleus}} + \hat T_{\text{electrons}}+\hat U_{\text{electron-nucleus}}+\hat U_{\text{electron-electron}}+\hat U_{\text{nucleus-nucleus}}$$
Under Born-Oppenheimer approximation, $\hat T_{\text{nucleus}} = 0$. So the equation about to be solved is:
$$(\hat T_{\text{electrons}}+\hat U_{\text{electron-nucleus}}+\hat U_{\text{electron-electron}}+\hat U_{\text{nucleus-nucleus}}) \psi_{\text{electron}} = E(\{ R_{\text{nucleus}}\}) \psi_{\text{electron}}$$
Clearly, $E(\{ R_{\text{nucleus}}\})$ gives a PES, and this PES is the relation:
$$\{ R_{\text{nucleus}} \} \rightarrow E_{\text{ground state electronic energy}}$$

However, when I learned about molecular dynamics (also in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy_surface)), a PES is defined to be the relation 
$$\{ R_{\text{nucleus}} \} \rightarrow E_{\text{energy of the system}}$$
**How do we find this map in practice? The only way I can think of is:**

1. We solve the electronic eigenequation for several $\{ R_{\text{nucleus}} \}$.
2. For each calculated $E(R_{\text{nucleus}})$ of electrons, we solve the equation 
   $$(\hat T_{\text{nucleus}} + E(R_{\text{nucleus}})) \phi_{\text{nucleus}} = E_{\text{nucleus}}\phi_{\text{nucleus}}$$
   to find the energy of the nucleus. (I have never learned how to solve an eigenequation of a nucleus in quantum chemistry)

Is this the way that we find the 'generalized' PES? When we say PES, which is the PES that we are referring to?

Comment: $\vec T_{nucleus}$ is the kinetic energy of the nucleus.  Normally under BO approx. the equations are solved at a series of fixed nuclear $R$; this  is what you describe initially and a PES results. If you want to describe motion over a PES during a reaction (dynamics) a common method is to use a LEPS (London-Eyring-Polyani-Sato) potential, which although empirical is based on known potentials obtained from spectroscopic experiments. See Steinfeld, Franscico, & Hase ' Chemical Kinetics & Dynamics' publ Prentice-Hall, or Hirst 'Molecular Structure & Reaction Dynamics'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PES $V({R})$ (where $R$ are the nuclear coordinates, electronic coordinates are usually denoted by $r$) is the electronic energy of any electronic state. So there is one PES for the ground state and many more all the excited states.

> Clearly, $E(\{ R_{\text{nucleus}}\})$ gives a PES, and this PES is the relation:
>   $$\{ R_{\text{nucleus}} \} \rightarrow E_{\text{ground state electronic energy}}$$
>   However, when I learned about molecular dynamics (also in [wikipedia][1]), a PES is defined to be the relation 
>   $$\{ R_{\text{nucleus}} \} \rightarrow E_{\text{energy of the system}}$$

"Energy of the system" is here referring to the "electronic system", so those two relations are the same.

> **How do we find this map in practice?**

1. Your first step is correct, we need to solve for the eigenvalues of the electronic Hamiltonian, for many different parameters $R$. Each electronic eigenvalue is one point on the PES. So in the end we get a discretized representation of the (actually continuous) PES $V(R)$.
2. The second step is to solve the nuclear Hamiltonian
   \begin{equation}
     \hat H_{\mathrm{nuc}} = \hat T_{\mathrm{nuc}} + V(R)
   \end{equation}
   There is only one such nuclear Hamiltonian for each PES.

So we need to do many times step 1, but only once step 2 (for each electronic state of interest).

#### How to solve the nuclear Hamiltonian?

This depends on what $V(R)$ looks like. In the simple case of a diatomic molecule, where $R$ becomes just the 1-dimensional internuclear distance, we may approximate it with a Morse potential or harmonic potential. We can fit the parameters of such analytic expressions to our discretized points from step 1 and then use the existing general solutions for those quantum systems. This will give us the vibrational eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

Another option is to solve the nuclear Hamiltonian on a numeric grid over $R$. The grid is either defined by the points chosen in step 1, or we can interpolate to a new grid. How to solve this is a topic on its own, so will just give one literature reference here: The book "*Introduction to Quantum Mechanics - A time-dependent Perspective*" by David Tannor covers many things related to your questions (although it can be challenging to read it).

Comment: So altought it is called "potential energy surface" it also includes kinetic energy, that of the electrons but not of the nuclei or I am missing something?

Comment: @adosar Yes, this is correct.